# Stopwords in Python 3

Tags: python, stop-words

I'm unable to import stopwords by using `from stop_words import stopwords` as they state that the module does not exist. Is there another command I can put in to remove around 900 stopwords?

Im aware of the 100+ stopwords command but I'm trying to find a command that removes around 900 stopwords.

Comment: Did you install the stop-words package?

Comment: Did you install the package first? You need to put `pip install stop-words` first if you are using pip

Comment: i am using jupyter is there a command for me to download the stop-words package in jupyter?

Comment: Maybe this article couod be helpful: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nltk` library for this easily. First you need to install it by going to a shell and `pip install nltk` (note for python 3 go for `pip3` instead of `pip`). After that you can easily got and download a stopwords corpus directly from python through nltk like this:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Now that you have the corpus downloaded, you can use it like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

This will print out a list of all the stopwords in english corpus. Other languages are available.